# Apache virtual host not catching all requests

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have 80 port requests redirected to 443 like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com mail.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com mail.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But in `other_vhosts_access.log` there are entries like this

```
example.com:80 51.222.253.14 - - [14/Sep/2022:09:01:41 +0300]...
vm12345.example.com:443 37.104.179.26 - - [14/Sep/2022:08:59:54 +0300]...
```

Why are they not catched by the named virtual hosts?

Comment: What access log is missing? Before redirection (HTTP) or or after redirection (HTTPS)? Did you check a `ssl_access.log` file too?

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the ssl access.log file. There are ordinary entries like `"GET /contact HTTP/1.0" 200 9386 "https://example.com/contact"`

Comment: The cache of a "Redirect permanent..." happens in the client browser even, so the sentence "no cached by the named virtual hosts" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted an incomplete configuration it is hard to say but probably there is a reason that the default virtual host matches requests for `example.com` rather than letting those get handled by the `example.com`  virtual host.

Check the output of (depending on the Linux distro) `apache2ctl -S`, or `apachectl -S` or `httpd -S` and pay particular attention that what Apache HTTP considers the default virtual host

That should show something like:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server api.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/api.example.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost api.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/api.example.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.api.example.com
         port 80 namevhost corp.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/corp.example.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.corp.example.com
         port 80 namevhost admin.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/admin.example.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.admin.example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
...
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html has an in-depth discussion on how virtual host matching works.